# How to position inline textbox and button using bootstrap above the Google Map?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to position the textbox and button inline and that's correct. But when I try different view example tablet view the textbox fit but the button stay in the position. Please see the image.

```
<input id="search" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search Location" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 10px; position: absolute; width: 30%; z-index: 1;">

<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.reload();" style="margin-left: 700px; width: 10%; margin-top: 10px; position: absolute; z-index: 1; background-color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #dce4ec; color: #2c3e50" value="Refresh" />

<div id="map" style="position: relative;"></div>
```

using this @chaitz9:

```
<input id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Location" style="margin-top: 10px; width: 30%; z-index: 1; margin-left: 100px;" type="text">
<input class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.reload();" style="margin-top: 10px; z-index: 1; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(220, 228, 236); color: rgb(44, 62, 80); width: 15%;" value="Refresh" type="button">
<div id="map" style="position: relative;"></div>
```

the output:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Try using this `CSS`. I have now wrapped the input fields into a div and given the div property of `display: table`. And to the input fields `display: table-cell`

```css
.loc_div{
     display: table !important;
     width:100%;
}

#search{
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    z-index: 1;
    position:relative;
    display:table-cell;  

}

.btn {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #dce4ec;
    color: #2c3e50;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 20%;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="loc_div">
  <input id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Location"  type="text">
  <input class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.reload();" value="Refresh" type="button">
</div>
<div id="map" style="position: relative;"></div>
```

Comment: Did you try adding the `exact` code I've shared above? It's working on my end even for Tablet View.